# Ruby on rails: create_fixtures memory problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I have to create around 100k records.
Those records are in the csv file and are being loaded using create_fixtures function.
It's slow on my development machine but it completes. The problem starts on production where we have memory limits per process which leads to killing the rake process.
I think it's because the create_fixtures is importing all the data into memory. Does anyone
know how to force it to import smaller chunks (before i cut one big csv into few smaller ones).

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it!

create_fixtures is designed for loading test data, which should be only as big as needed to exercise a feature. It's **not** intended for loading thousands of records onto a production (or any other kind of) database. If it's a one-off then maybe OK, but as a regular thing it would make me very nervous.

If your data is simple enough, by which I mean a simple `String#split` would work, then that should probably be your approach, something like

```
File.foreach(csv_file_path) do |line|
  fields = line.split(/,/)
  # create records from the array of fields
end
```

Otherwise (i.e. you may have string values with quotes or commas, missing field values or multiple record formats, that sort of thing) you should probably look at the [CSV library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html), which is already part of the Ruby 1.8.6 install, or better yet, look at the [FasterCSV Gem](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/), which replaces CSV in 1.9 onwards.

UPDATE: Handily, Ryan Bates just [posted a screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data) on the vexatious topic of seed data...

Comment: While i understand that it's bad practice to load fixtures in production (no validations for example), for some data (like countries/cities/etc...) it's a necessity. I found nice dicussion here: http://railspikes.com/2008/2/1/loading-seed-data
(looking not for fixture memory problem but for how people handle seeding production.)

Comment: Maybe I'm reading a different part. I see this "I don’t like fixtures because they don’t validate data". The comments to that post mention ar-extensions, which is useful if DB bulk-write speed is an issue. I'm not quibbling with the need for seed data (is that all you're trying to do - the question isn't clear), I just think you may be better off if you give up on trying to use fixture loading for something it wasn't designed for.

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading/parsing the CSV? I think I'd use Ruby's File utils to open and read and parse every line myself.